# unable to cast of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[System.String]' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, linq

I need the column value(FundSpreadDurationContribution) of a data table(residing in dataset) through LINQ which fetches the above error (heading)

Elaborated: when a row cell has value *Spread Duration--IR Swap*, need the corresponding column cell *FundSpreadDurationContribution* value.

```
 double testvalue = Convert.ToDouble(raptorDS.Tables[RaptorTable.DurationContribBySector].AsEnumerable().Where(r =>
                                         r.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.FundCode) == fundDescriptionColumn &&
                                         r.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.Component) == Component.B8_DURATION_CONTRIBUTION_BY_SECTOR &&
                                         r.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.Sector) == "Spread Duration--IR Swap").Select(s => s.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.FundSpreadDurationContribution)))
```

I am learner of LINQ.

Comment: use `First` instead for `Select`

Comment: @un-lucky No, use `First` (or a variant) instead of `Where`

Comment: Modified the last line to                                                                  r.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.Sector) == "Spread Duration--IR Swap").Select(s => s.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.FundSpreadDurationContribution)).First()); lands me up in cannot convert lambda expression to delegate

Comment: Try following : 
double?[] testvalue = raptorDS.Tables[RaptorTable.DurationContribBySector].AsEnumerable().Where(r =>
                                         r.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.FundCode) == fundDescriptionColumn &&
                                         r.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.Component) == Component.B8_DURATION_CONTRIBUTION_BY_SECTOR &&
                                         r.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.Sector) == "Spread Duration--IR Swap").Select(s => double.Parse(s.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.FundSpreadDurationContribution))).ToArray();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// First check if this query will return any results 
var records =
    raptorDS.Tables[RaptorTable.DurationContribBySector].AsEnumerable().Where(r =>
    r.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.FundCode) == fundDescriptionColumn &&
    r.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.Component) == Component.B8_DURATION_CONTRIBUTION_BY_SECTOR &&
    r.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.Sector) == "Spread Duration--IR Swap");

// CHeck if any result
if (records.Any())
{
    // We have results so let's go through each record and try to get that value
    // converted to a double
    List<double> values = new List<double>();
    List<string> badValues = new List<string>();
    foreach (var thisRecord in records)
    {
        var fsdc = thisRecord.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.FundSpreadDurationContribution);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fsdc))
        {
            double val = 0;
            if (double.TryParse(fsdc, val))
            {
                values.Add(val);
            }
            else
            {
                badValues.Add(fsdc);
            }
        }
    }

    // Do whatever you need to do with values here

    // and bad values here
}
```

Comment: I tried the above and this lands me up in error "System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)"

Comment: What happens if you execute this: var val = raptorDS.Tables[RaptorTable.DurationContribBySector].AsEnumerable();

Comment: resultview of var retrieves 53 rows.

Comment: see my edit. It is more error prone and clear with comments

Comment: another edit if you want to track values which could not be converted to double.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts in explanation and code logic. This is very informative. Still i have got a simplest solution which i giving here for everybody use. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`Where` returns a collection, which cannot be converted to a `double`.  Use one of these Linq methods to get one answer to convert:

- `Single`
- `SingleOrDefault`
- `First`
- `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: i tried by first and that fetches me "System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)"

Answer (score 0):

This is just playing around with Datatypes which fixed the type casting issue

```
 var sumFundSpreadDuration = raptorDS.Tables[RaptorTable.DurationContribBySector].AsEnumerable().Where(r =>
                                             r.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.FundCode) == fundDescriptionColumn &&
                                             r.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.Component) == Component.B8_DURATION_CONTRIBUTION_BY_SECTOR &&
                                             r.Field<string>(RaptorColumns.Sector) == "Spread Duration--IR Swap")
                                             .Select(s => s.Field<double?>(RaptorColumns.FundSpreadDurationContribution)).FirstOrDefault();
```

If you see the datatype of variable is changed to Variant from double. Also, the datatype of column FundSpreadDurationContribution is changed to double. Thanks to [CodingYoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4228458/codingyoshi) for providing insights of datatypes in linq